# Running Python RESTful API on Amazon EC2

Tags: python, rest, amazon-ec2

I have a working RESTful API written in python which works well in my local machine. Now I am having some serious trouble getting started with Amazon EC2. 
I have managed to create an account and managed to create an instance , and lauch the instance as well. I have connected to the instance via ssh and passed by credentials. 
I have the required file (app.py) on EC2. But I have no idea how to run it. Obviously if I run it from my ssh terminal, it still is a local service.

How to make it a public RESTful API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like a firewall, you have to open up the server's ports. You do this via adding rules to the security group while you're configuring the EC2 instance. Add the HTTP rule, and allow all IP addresses (0.0.0.0/0) to access that. See here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#adding-security-group-rule

You can also set SSH, HTTPS, and other secure ports here (but you probably don't want everyone accessing SSH!).

Comment: I added a HTTP rule which allows all the IP address to access it. So assume the public IP of instance is X.X.X.X . When i try accessing X.X.X.X/todo . It says website not found

Comment: There's multiple IP addresses, but it's best to go for the public DNS name. You can find that in the instance description for consoles. If you deployed a web-app called todo, it'd be http://[ec2-hostname]/todo